# Actualizar formularios multiples impresos por un query

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Este formulario se imprime las cantidades de veces según los resultados, pero ajax solo me atrapa el primer formulario, los demas formularios me los envia saltando a la otra pagina.
Aqui mi codigo en Ajax. :)

```js
<script language="javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
    $().ajaxStart(function() {
        $('#loading').show();
        $('#result').hide();
    }).ajaxStop(function() {
        $('#loading').hide();
        $('#result').fadeIn('slow');
  $("#result").fadeOut(1000);
    });
   
    $('#h').submit(function() {
  
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "ercc.php",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        })        
        return false;
    }); 
})
// ]]></script>
```

```html
<?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hclinico WHERE id = '$id' ");?>
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){?>
    
<form id="h" name="h" method="post" autocomplete="off" action="ercc.php">

<table id="m" width="30%" height="311" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="2%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="46%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="2%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="36%">&nbsp;</td>
    <?php echo "<td><a href='ppdf2.php?idd=".$row['idd']."' target='_blank'> <img src='print.png' width='20' height='20' /> </a></td>";  ?>
    <!--<td width="14%"><img src="print.png" width="20" height="20" /></td>-->
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <?php echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='idd[]' value='".$row['idd']."' /></td>";?>
    <td><div id="result"></div></td>
    <td>Sintomas</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><table width="20" border="0">
      <tr><td>Cédula</td>
        <td><input name="id[]" type="text" value=" <?php echo $row['id'] ?> "  readonly/>
        <label for="cédula"></label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Talla</td>
        <td><label for="talla"></label>
          <input type="text" name="talla[]" value=" <?php echo $row['talla'] ?> "  required /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>F.C.</td>
        <td><label for="F.C."></label>
          <input type="text" name="fc[]" value=" <?php echo $row['fc'] ?> "  required /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Fecha</td>
        <td><label for="fecha"></label>
          <?php echo " <input type='date' name='fecha[]' value='".$row['fecha']."' required/>";?>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hora</td>
        <td><label for="hora"></label>
          <input type="text" name="hora[]" value=" <?php echo $row['hora'] ?> "  required /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>P.A.</td>
        <td><label for="pa"></label>
          <input type="text" name="pa[]" value=" <?php echo $row['pa'] ?> "  required /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>F.R.</td>
        <td><label for="fr"></label>
          <input type="text" name="fr[]" value=" <?php echo $row['fr'] ?> "  required /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Peso</td>
        <td><label for="peso"></label>
          <input type="text" name="peso[]" value=" <?php echo $row['peso'] ?> "  required /></td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <?php $sint=$row['sint']; ?>
    <td><textarea name="textfield" cols="30" rows="12" name="sint[]"  type="text" value=" <?php $sint ?> " ><?php echo $sint; ?></textarea></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    
    
    <td><input type="submit" name="mysubmit"  value="Actualizar" /></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
  <label for="textfield3"></label>
</form>

<?php }
```

Comment: Hola @Leonardo y bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. Si tienes un rato te agradeceríamos que echaras un vsitazo al [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y te pasaras por el [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) para entender mejor como funciona este sitio. El idioma oficial del sitio es el español y las preguntas y respuestas deben de ir en este idioma. Por favor, edita tu pregunta traduciendola al español o dirígete al sitio en inglés: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La propiedad `id` debe ser **única** por DOM, si duplicas el formulario N veces y haces referencia a `$('#h').submit(function() {` entonces solamente se enviará el primer formulario que tome el browser.

Usa clases para obtener un array de elementos en tu selector jquery, estas si se pueden duplicar. Considera lo siguiente:

```
<form class="para_envio verde" id="h1"> ... </form>
<form class="para_envio rojo" id="h2"> ... </form>
<form class="para_envio azul" id="h3"> ... </form>
```

Y en JQuery:

```
$('.para_envio').submit(function() {
  console.log(this);
}
```

Como resultado tienes que cada formulario va a imprimir en consola el elemento que está en contexto al ser enviado. Lo que resta son las reglas de negocio que quieras usar.

Comment: Gracias, fue de mucha ayuda.

Comment: Un placer, que gusto que te haya servido. Saludos.